# Does New York Pass entitle you to visit Ellis Island from NJ, USA?

Tags: sightseeing, new-york-city, ferries

Can I board the ferry to the Ellis Island/Liberty Island in Liberty Park, NJ with the New York Pass or is Battery Park the only option?

[New York Pass website description](https://www.newyorkpass.com/En/new-york-attractions/tickets/Statue-of-Liberty/) suggests that you should board at the Battery Park but maybe any of the people here tried it and will be able to reply quicker than their customer service.

Comment: Hmm, good question. The website of Statue Cruises (the official ferry concessionaire) doesn't specify one way or the other as to where you can start the trip, though it seems to be no trouble at all to start from one point but return to the other.

Comment: @choster: When on the island and embarking on a return ferry, do they check your ticket at all? I mean, since you are on the island it means that you must have purchased the return ticket before, doesn't it?

Comment: New york pass customer service replied: "you must board in Battery Park". On the other hand on live chat on http://www.statuecruises.com/ I learned that it doesn't matter where you board. Bam! Confusion, confusion, I suppose I wlll have to test it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of the information available it should.

The [Statue Cruises](http://www.statuecruises.com/) does accept New York Pass as a ticket option as it is listed on their site.  And if you click on [Book Now](http://www.statuecruises.com/choose_tickets.aspx) it will give you an option to reserve seating on either the Battery Park Ferry or on the Liberty Park Ferry.  You can also see the same mentioned in their [FAQ](http://www.statuecruises.com/frequently-asked-questions.aspx) which allows you to enter from one side and leave to the other.

Though I would question the wisdom of buying a New York Pass and going to Liberty Park in NJ to go to the Statue of Liberty or Ellis Island.

Comment: I will be staying in NJ, 30 minutes on foot from the Liberty Park,  so it would save a lot of time for me not to take PATH to New York only to take a cruise to virtually the same place I started:)

Comment: I will accept this answer as Statue Cruises customer service informed me I can enter in any location (I did in Battery Park in the end though). But indeed, once you are on the islands no one checks which boat you are getting on (to NY or NJ)